# Strcpy does not work correctly with char arrays

Tags: arrays, c, char, strcpy

I get the following output when I run the code below:

```
Matrikel: 01717
Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)
```

Code:

```
char infos[255];
char matrikelnr[5];

sprintf(matrikelnr, "%d", s->matnr);
size_t n = strlen(matrikelnr);

while (n != 5) {
    memmove(matrikelnr + 1, matrikelnr, 5);
    matrikelnr[0] = '0';
    n = strlen(matrikelnr);
}

printf("Matrikel: %s", matrikelnr);
strcpy(&infos[0], matrikelnr);
printf("DEBUG");
```

I already tried:
`strcpy(infos[0], matrikelnr);`
and
`strcpy(infos[0], matrikelnr);`

The `strcpy` seems to have a problem. Could you please help me with the solution?

Thanks already!

Comment: size of 5 for `matrikelnr` sure isn't much .. did you leave enough room for the `NUL` terminator?

Comment: Whats 's'? What is that code supposed to do? why are you writing a literal '0' to the first character of the string each round in the loop?

Comment: @yano The maximum is 5 numbers in the `matrikelnr` array. Do I need a larger array?

Comment: What is the value of `s->matnr`? Have you tried catching the crash (which is what it is) using a debugger? Exactly where in your code does it happen? What are the values of all involved variables at the time of the crash?

Comment: By the way, `memmove(matrikelnr+1, matrikelnr, 5)` ***will*** write out of bounds. Going out of bounds leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @lulle I have some restriction from the university to store the matriculation number as an unsigned integer. The problem is: what if the number starts with two 0's? I need exact five characters (the five numbers of the matriculation numer) in the array to continue

Comment: And you seem to need a reminder that strings in C are really ***null-terminated** strings*. A string with five characters needs space for six, to fit the terminator.

Comment: What is the desired output. What this program is supposed to do? Without this information, we are unable to help

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by "5 numbers". `char matrikelnr[5];` is an array of 5 chars, meaning the largest number you can safely `sprintf` to it (in base 10) is 9999. If `s->matnr` is larger than that, you're out of bounds. You must leave room for the `NUL` terminator. And as already mentioned, your `memmove` is out of bounds.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude what do I have to change to avoid memmove to write out of bound? I'm still a beginner...

Comment: Actually you don't have to use the loop and `memmove` at all. The `sprintf` call could easily pad with zeroes if you ask it to. I also recommend that you use `snprintf` instead to make sure you don't have it write out of bounds. Like `snprintf(matrikelnr, sizeof matrikelnr, "%04d", s->matnr)`

Comment: On a last note, when using `printf` for debugging output it help to remember that output to `stdout` (which is where `printf` is writing) is ***line**-buffered* when connected to a terminal. Which means output will be flushed (actually output) when printing a newline `\n`. And if `stdout` is not connected to a terminal (which can happen for some IDE's) then explicitly call `fflush(stdout)` to make sure the output is written. Or use `fprintf` to write to `stderr` which is unbuffered.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Your suggestion would work if it's always only four numbers. But sometimes it's three or even five and i don't have to add the 0's at all... Our lecturer set us a lot of traps :D

Comment: If you can have up to five-digit numbers, then first of all you need an array of *six* characters, to fit the terminator. Then adjust the number to fit your array. So if you have `char matrikelnr[11];` (which will fit all digits of a 32-bit `unsigned int` including terminator) then you can use `snprintf(matrikelnr, sizeof matrikelnr, "%010d", s->matnr)`

Comment: And for future questions please include the full and complete assignment or exercise in the question itself, including all requirements and limitations. So we don't have to guess and correct ourselves as you give us more details piece by piece. Please refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 1):

The main problem of your code is that you don't provide enough room for the string-terminating character `'\0'`. Each C string needs this to mark the end of the string. If you need to store strings with 5 characters, the variable needs to provide space for 6 characters.

However, your task can be solved much simpler, if you use standard formatting facilities. Change your call of `sprintf()` like this:

```c
char matrikelnr[5 + 1];

sprintf(matrikelnr, "%05d", s->matnr);
```

The `'0'` is for using zeroes as filling character, and the `'5'` for a width of (at least) 5 characters.

I hope that your numbers are never greater than 99999.

Please read the documentation for details, and consider to use safer functions like `snprintf()`.

Comment: Using `snprintf` is highly recommended to stop wondering about numbers greater than `99999` or below `-9999`. Alternatively `"%.5"` also pads the number with initial zeroes to the specified minimum number of digits (`5`), whereas `"%05"` pads the output with initial zeroes to the specified width, after a possible sign: `printf("%05d", -4)` outputs `-0004` but `printf("%.5d", -4)` outputs `-00004`.

Comment: Thanks @chqrlie for your comment, there is so much more to know about formatting. It would not fit in a crispy answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it is almost impossible to tell you exactly what causes the problem with the given code, but I could give you some advice from my experience. Some functions in c (e.g. memmove(), strcpy()) does not have perfect design as their behavior is undefined according to context. So first, make sure NULL Bytes are set correctly in your variables(that can cause many problems in c when it comes to char*). I think you don't have null bytes in your char arrays at right place, that causes problem for string functions(function cannot understand when to stop while copying string from one place to another). ps. I mean char* when I say string you know. This kind of problems also cause "segmentation fault" quite often.